# git credneital-manager-st is not a git command on Windows 10

Tags: git

When I run the command

```
 git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=manager-st push -v --tags origin Br123:Br123
```

I get the error

```
git: 'credential-manager-st' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://host'
```

I am running Windows 10 Version 1703 with git version 2.13.2.windows.1   The command is originally from SourceTree (v2.0.20.1).

Despite various debugging and checking the Windows Credential Manager, I am having no success in resolving the issue.

I can `push/sync` directly from Visual Studio 2015. I believe this uses library calls and not `git.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem that you try to use the git credential manager on Windows.

I found this open-source tool (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) which can be installed and used afterwards like this:

```
git credential-manager [<command> [<args>]]
```